# Laravel job for Mailables, common object

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5.5

I created a Laravel job for sending emails and I have multiple classes inheriting from `Mailable`.

My Job class:

```
class SendMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $emailObject;

    public function __construct($emailObject)
    {
        $this->emailObject = $emailObject;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        \Mail::to($this->emailObject->user->email)->queue($this->emailObject);
    }
}
```

I execute this with:

```
 $this->dispatch(new SendMail(new Profile($user)));
```

or

```
$this->dispatch(new SendMail(new Newsletter($user)));
```

I would like to create object or pattern which will allow me to create a `constructor` with an object in my job. Like this:

```
class SendMail{

        public function __construct(CommonMailObject $emailObject)
        {
            $this->emailObject = $emailObject;
        }
}
```

eg. Profile class:

```
class Profile extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('', '')
                    ->subject('')
                    ->view(EmailType::PROFILE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking our opinion, to see if your design is good or not?

Comment: I'm asking for opinion and I don't known how to create `CommonMailObject` for all Mailable class.

Comment: Why not just declare `__construct(Mailable $mailable)`? If `Newsletter` extends that class, as `Profile`, you can pass either that way.

Comment: @yivi I try to do that but I don't known how to access `$user` object from `Profile` or `Newsletter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just declare that your `SendMail` class depends on a `Mailable` object.

E.g.:

```
class SendMail{

        public function __construct(Mailable $mailable)
        {
            $this->emailObject = $mailable;
        }
}
```

That way you can do both:

```
$this->dispatch(new SendMail(new Profile($user)));
```

and

```
$this->dispatch(new SendMail(new Newsletter($user)));
```

In the [Mailable](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php) class most properties are public. To get the address you need to get the `to` property, which is an array (because it can handle multiple email addresses).

So you'd just have to access:

```
$this->emailObject->to
```

Haven't tested it, but *probably*:

```
\Mail::to($this->emailObject->to)->queue($this->emailObject);
```

should work.

I'll leave the fine-tuning to you.

Comment: Ok, how to access email field in job? `$this->emailObject->user->email`?

Comment: email field from `User` object